# Website sidebar CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, sidebar

I want the sidebar to end just before the footer.
[The line shows where the sidebar should end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T01z5.png)

The first one is the CSS code of the sidebar. The second one is the HTML code of the whole page.

```css
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  background: #d1bdbd;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 65px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="sidebar" style="text-align: center">
  <h3>Current Time:</h3>
  <embed src=http://flash-clocks.com/free-flash-clocks-blog-topics/free-flash-clock-161.swf width=200 height=100 wmode=transparent type=application/x-shockwave-flash>
  <h3>Most recent posts:</h3>
  @foreach (var post in ViewBag.SidebarPosts) {
  <div><a href="Posts/Details/@post.Id" class="hyperlink"> @post.Title</a>
  </div>
  }
</div>

@foreach (var post in Model) {
<section class="row">
  <article class="post col-md-8">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="/Posts/Details/@post.Id" class="hyperlink">@post.Title</a></h2>
    <div class="about">
      Posted on <i>@post.Date</i>
      @if (post.Author!=null) { @: by <i>@post.Author.FullName</i>
      }
    </div>
    <div class="body">@Html.Raw(Utils.CutText(post.Body)) @Html.ActionLink("Read more", $"Details/{post.Id}", "Posts")</div>
  </article>
</section>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your footer needs to be set to clear:both;  that would be the section that says 
© 2016...

You may find its actual class in a page template or in the shared layout.   If you are running firefox or chrome you can inspect the element and then set it to clear both.

Comment: Mm this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you can use the flexbox layout ([css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Here's my solution for your case : http://cssdeck.com/labs/ptuzfrep

```
header{background: yellow;}
section.container{
  display: flex;
}
section.content{
  background: red;
}
section.sidebar{
  background: blue;
  max-width: 300px;
}
footer{background: green;}


<header>Header</header>
<section class="container">
  <section class="content">
    content
  </section>
  <section class="sidebar">
    content
  </section>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please avoid *just* posting links in your answer. Links can go bad, and might prove essential for your answer to be relevant in future - this applies to both your code snippets and reference text. Instead, consider adding some relevant code snippets to answer the question, along with a short explanation of how it works (us developers love to know how stuff works); and by all means - include a link for the reference